# two operations on two lists in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I'm a bit of a Haskell newbie. Let's say that i have two infinite lists of numbers `A` and `B` and I want to create another infinite list `C` which contains a sequence of `x+y`'s and `x-y`'s where `x <- A` and `y <- B`, i.e., `C` grows by 2 in every loop; what's the most clever way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make an infinite list of two-element lists and concatenate them.

```
concat [[x+y, x-y] | (x, y) <- zip listA listB]
```

Comment: why using zip and not just | x <- listA, y <- listB?

Comment: @nist: Because they're not the same. That gives you every _combination_ of items from the lists, but here we want to match them up pairwise. However, using the `ParallelListComp` extension, you can write `| x <- listA | y <- listB`, which is equivalent to using `zip`.

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't want the most clever way, since by definition it would be too clever for you to debug :-)

An obvious way would be to zip the infinite streams together, like so:

```
zipWith k as bs
    where
        k a b = (a + b, a - b)
```

Comment: this is what I thought originally but it returns a list of tuples (which, granted, I can unzip)

Comment: Indeed, but it has the benefit of retaining the structure of algorithm.

Comment: `concat $ zipWith k as bs where k a b = [a + b, a - b]`

Answer (score 1):

For infinite lists only it's just

```
mkList (x:xs) (y:ys) = x+y : x-y : mkList xs ys
```

and to support finite lists, too, you've to add the base case

```
mkList _ _ = []
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f xs = concat . zipWith go xs where 
       go x y = map (($y).($x)) [(+),(-)]
```